# Terraform Cloud Run Service URL

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

I create a cloud run service like so

```
terraform {
  required_version = ">= 1.1.2"
  required_providers {
    google = {
      source  = "hashicorp/google"
      version = "~> 4.1.0"
    }
    google-beta = {
      source  = "hashicorp/google-beta"
      version = "~> 4.2.0"
    }
  }
}

provider "google" {
  project     = "main_project"
  region      = "us-central-1"
  credentials = "<my-key-path>"
}

resource "google_cloud_run_service" "default" {
  name     = "cloudrun-srv"
  location = "us-central1"

  template {
    spec {
      containers {
        image = "us-docker.pkg.dev/cloudrun/container/hello"
      }
    }
  }

  traffic {
    percent         = 100
    latest_revision = true
  }
}
```

I want to save the value of the service url that is created - https://default-hml2qtrgfq-uw.a.run.app using an output variable. something like

```
output "cloud_run_instance_url" {
  value = google_cloud_run_service.default.url
}
```

This gives me an error:

terraform plan
╷
│ Error: Unsupported attribute
│
│   on main.tf line 40, in output "cloud_run_instance_url":
│   40:   value = google_cloud_run_service.default.url
│
│ This object has no argument, nested block, or exported attribute named "url".
╵

How do I get this output value and assign it to a variable so that other services like cloud scheduler can point to it?

Comment: Are you asking for https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/cloud_run_service#url?

Comment: yes! So it looks like I need to somehow bind status.url to an output variable that other modules can use

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you declare an output for the [url resource attribute](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/cloud_run_service#url) like:

```
output "cloud_run_instance_url" {
  value = google_cloud_run_service.default.status.0.url
}
```

then it will be available for resolution (such as for inputs to other modules) at the scope where the module is declared in the namespace `module.<declared module name>.cloud_run_instance_url`. For example, if this module is declared in the root module config, then it can be resolved at that namespace elsewhere in the root module config.

Comment: Im still getting an error "This object has no argument, nested block, or exported attribute named "url"". I updated the question to include all the terraform code I used to get this error

Comment: @BigBoy1337 My fault; I answered too quickly without spending a few more seconds looking at the doc. Answer updated.

Comment: With the updated code  value = google_cloud_run_service.default.status["url"], I am getting "The given key does not identify an element in this collection value: a number is required."

Comment: @BigBoy1337 Yeah google configured that attribute schema to be a block instead of the normal object for some reason for that structure. So it also needs the `0` element to parse correctly. Updating answer again.